# How to fix 'crypto_nonexistent' error when using MSAL with Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, msal-angular

I build the angular universal and MSAL B2C project. After run build:ssr and run dev:ssr I get an error: ERROR BrowserAuthError: crypto_nonexistent: The crypto object or function is not available. Detail:Browser crypto, msCrypto, or msrCrypto interfaces not available.

[image]

```
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.5.7",
"@azure/msal-browser": "2.37",
"@angular/core": "^15.0.2",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
```

Please help me clarify why getting this error and a solution to resolve it.

Comment: This is because that `crypto` object is not available on node. You need to use a polyfill for that part https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/webcrypto